# What is the best haskell documentation available online?

Tags: haskell, documentation, reference

With Java, Groovy, and Python, it is easy to find the standard, complete, easy to navigate documentation for the language.

I'm starting to learn Haskell, and I'm not sure where to find this.  In particular, it doesn't seem to exist at haskell.org.

Comment: I for one found hoogle (http://haskell.org/hoogle/) often more useful than a long listing of functions.

Comment: What sort of documentation are you looking for?  Language specification?  Language tutorials?  API docs?  I could probably list off a whole ton of resources but without more information about what you're looking for I feel like that would probably be a waste of your time to sift through it for what you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you scroll down on http://haskell.org/, on the left sidebar under "Libraries", you will find a set of documentation of [all libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html) (called packages), which might be what you're looking for.  However, be aware that it is an extremely large database, because it includes user-submitted content as well as standard libraries.

The two online search engines "[Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html)" and "[Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/)" might be able to help you.  You can search by function name, type signature, or both.  As far as I know, the only difference is that "Hayoo" searches the entire database, whereas "Hoogle" searches the standard libraries plus a few common extras.  I would recommend Hoogle, because it generally gives you what you want, and is in my experience more reliable.

While we're on the subject, I personally think that http://learnyouahaskell.com/ is a great resource for learning Haskell if you've never seen a functional language before.

Comment: Thanks much.  I'll bookmark Hoogle immediately.

Comment: In about 2 weeks Hoogle will also search the entire database - I'm actively working on it.

Comment: @Neil That is very exciting news!

Answer (score 7):

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12-latest/html/

Answer (score 7):

Sorry can't comment yet, so here.

Hoogle is not just online search engine. Check [ghci integration](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle#GHCi_Integration).

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for the same thing:

Wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:Haskell
Good Intro: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Not much help, but it's a start.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It addresses the question and provides some unique information (haskellwiki link).

Comment: Is there some quality standard I should be aware of?  I've just started trying to contribute, and I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/ is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download.html#snapshots

Comment: The person how have downvoted, should be kind enough to tell me what's wrong with this answer. Below HEAD branch e.g is a link labeled Documentation which leads to the online documentation of Haskell libraries..

Answer (score 3):

http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this intro to natuaral lang. processing: http://nlpwp.org/book/